# Регулярные выражения, фунция string.ascii_letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Как сделать так, чтобы функция **string.ascii_letters** не трогала пробелы

```
import string
s = '321eqweds***! .1dewq'
result = ''.join(c for c in s if c in string.ascii_letters)
print(result)
```

Выведет на экран: `eqwedsdewq`
А нужно что бы : `eqweds dewq`

Comment: `ascii_letters` - это не функция, а строка, на основе которой вы можете создать свою строку, добавив к ней необходимые символы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярка:

- `[^a-z ]` поиск символов, что не относятся к диапазону от `a` до `z` и к пробелу ()

Пример:

```
import re

text = '321eqweds***! .1dewq'

new_text = re.sub('[^a-z ]', '', text)
print(new_text)
# eqweds dewq
```